# Can I use the temporary file generated by DiskFileItemFactory to parse the file before uploading?

Tags: html, servlets, jquery

Example:

```
DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(1*1024*1024); //1 MB
fileItemFactory.setRepository(tmpDir);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. If the file is on the server's disk, then it's already been uploaded. Parsing the file before uploading is only possible on the client side. But HTML/JavaScript isn't capable of that. Your best bet would then be a Java Applet, but that's pretty cumbersome. Why don't you just parse the file after uploading in the server side?

Comment: Thanks, I thought there could be other options, I'll go with the uploading in server side and then parsing it :)